# UE5 Crashing without reason EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00001ff003fe0030

Tags: exception, crash, sequence, unreal-engine5

My Unreal Engine is crashing over and over again. I have tried couple of things to fix it.

I am using a RTX3080, latest driver, latest windows updates, latest unreal version.
The problem is, that it keeps happening without any reason. Most of the Time when I am saving my project, but also when I create a new Asset or set a keyframe.

First I thought it has something to do with my VR, but then I deinstalled everything and it keeps crashing.
I am mainly using the sequencer

Here is the Callstack:

Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00001ff003fe0030

UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor_MovieSceneTracks
UnrealEditor_MovieSceneTracks
UnrealEditor_MovieSceneTracks
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_MovieScene
UnrealEditor_Sequencer
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor_UnrealEd
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll

If you could help me, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Looks like there seems to be an issue while playing a track through a media player in your level. You could take it out and see if the playback of it is connected to the crash. If this keeps happening, I'd recommend installing debug symbols for your engine version and attach a debugger to see what is really going on.

Comment: Happy to help. Let us know if you find a solution ;)